# Unix background processes stop running

Tags: unix, xterm, x11

From my Windows 7 box with Cygwin, I ssh into a Solaris box.

Windows box:

```
# uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 KSTLINTC20V1335 1.7.9(0.237/5/3) 2011-03-29 10:10 i686 Cygwin
```

Solaris box:

```
$uname -a
SunOS dncs 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc
```

Suppose I log into the Solaris box from the Windows box:

`ssh -Y user@host`

I make sure my `DISPLAY` is set, and I open a xterm:

`/usr/openwin/bin/xterm`

It open on my display.

Now, I suspend it with `CTRL-z`.  Then I type `bg` to put it into the background.  I can't log out of the first window until that xterm process is finished.

So I tried to run it as such

`nohup /usr/openwin/bin/xterm &`

The xterm runs in the background as expected, but when I try to disconnect from my ssh session in the original window, it tells me I have running jobs.  I thought `nohup` disconnected the process from the terminal.

And if I close the original window, then my xterm goes away too.

I also tried this, from the windows box:

`ssh -Y user@host /usr/openwin/bin/xterm`

The xterm opens as expected.  However, if I suspend it and put it into the background:  `CTRL-z` and `bg`, the xterm will not respond.  I cannot type anything into it until I bring it into the foreground with `fg`.

Why is this happening?  What do I need to do "revive" my xterms (and other X window processes) which I put them into the background?

I can run the following, and it works as expected:

`nohup ssh -Y user@host /usr/openwin/bin/xterm &`

Comment: this is the question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Not ServerFault - that's for server administration / infrastructure type questions. This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: `nohup` doesn't know anything about X11 connections, which is what `xterm` would be using to show a window.

Comment: Set up your `DISPLAY` to connect to your local X-server by IP address or hostname, instead of using `ssh` X11 connection forwarding. `ssh` will generally refuse to exit as long as you have open secondary channels like forwarded X11 connections, `sftp` channels, etc...